# Not able to connect to Quorum node from Nethereum

Tags: quorum, nethereum

I am not able to connect to Quorumchain using Nethereum. Below is my code and error response.

I have verified and the port is open in the machine. I am running on a Linux machine, Ubuntu 18.04. I couldn't see any issue in code or port, could someone help to resolve this problem.

I am able to connect to node using geth attach on command line.

Code:

using Nethereum.Quorum;
using Nethereum.RPC.Eth.DTOs;
using Nethereum.Web3;
using Nethereum.Web3.Accounts;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QuorumTest
{
class Program
{
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
Console.WriteLine("Hello.. This is the Quorum Test!");
try
{
var web3Quorum = new Web3Quorum("http://localhost/8001");
var coinbaseAcct = await web3Quorum.Eth.CoinBase.SendRequestAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Coinbase is: {0}", coinbaseAcct);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
Console.Write(e);
}

}
}
}

Response:

gethadmin@manojpoc2:~/dotnetapps/QuorumTest/QuorumTest$ dotnet run
Hello.. This is the Quorum Test!
Nethereum.JsonRpc.Client.RpcClientUnknownException: Error occurred when trying to send rpc requests(s) ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result() at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask1 creationTask) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
at Nethereum.JsonRpc.Client.RpcClient.SendAsync(RpcRequestMessage request, String route)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Nethereum.JsonRpc.Client.RpcClient.SendAsync(RpcRequestMessage request, String route)
at Nethereum.JsonRpc.Client.ClientBase.SendInnerRequestAsyncT
at Nethereum.JsonRpc.Client.ClientBase.SendInnerRequestAsyncT
at Nethereum.JsonRpc.Client.ClientBase.SendRequestAsyncT
at QuorumTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/gethadmin/dotnetapps/QuorumTest/QuorumTest/Program.cs:line 18

_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue in my code, I did not use proper url, I need to give the http://url:port

after correcting my url, the connection is fine